# will exiting the overloaded assignment operator invoke destructor to delete the object

Tags: c++, destructor, assignment-operator

In c++ the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object {

public:
   Object(int id){
     cout << "Construct(" << id << ")" << endl;
     m_id = id;
   }

   Object(const Object& obj){
      cout << "Copy-construct(" << obj.m_id << ")" << endl;
      m_id = obj.m_id;
   }

   Object& operator=(const Object& obj){
      cout << m_id << " = " << obj.m_id << endl;
      m_id = obj.m_id;
      return *this;
   }

   ~Object(){
       cout << "Destruct(" << m_id << ")" << endl;
   }
private:
   int m_id;

};

int main(){
   Object v1(1);
   cout << "( a )" << endl;
   Object v2(2);
   v2 = v1;
}
```

and associated output

```
Construct(1)
( a )
Construct(2)
2 = 1
```

Why after the `=` operator, `destructor` isn't called. the `obj in operator =` should exit the scope and should invoke a `destructor` upon itself? Isn't it so?

Comment: You're passing `obj` in by reference, so no, the destructor should not be called on it

Comment: That isn't all of  the output to this program. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/70Q08q). And no, there is not implicit or explicit temporary object creation in your assignment operator as you're calling it, so that itself will introduce neither constructions or destructions. Perhaps you're thinking about the copy/swap idiom and how it constructs temporaries for exception-safe assignment. (it would be somewhat pointless in this case, but were some of the Object members *dynamic* it would be significantly more important).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. 'obj' wasn't created in the scope so it isn't destroyed in the scope. It's a *parameter,* and it's a *reference.* The actual object is elsewhere.

Comment: What? It's constructed from the argument `2` by one of the `Object` constructors. It should absolutely be destroyed after the ass.op. returns. I blame optimisations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's destroyed at the end of main(). It isn't destroyed *by exiting the overloaded assignment operator's scope.* Read the question.r Read the part where he asks why the destructor *isn't* invoked.

Comment: It's destroyed at the end of the _full-expression_ in which it appears, which is the function call in which it was constructed, but as I'm stuck on mobile with limited net mobility and not enough caring to scroll up and study the question again, I shan't stake my rep on that :)

Comment: Ok i lied and looked and I think the question is confused. I can see why one may expect `v2`'s ctor argument's dtor to be invoked immediately but, as it talks about `op=` instead, you are correct of course. I wonder whether he meant to ask about the former as I'd blazenly assumed in my initial comment.

Comment: @LighnessRacesInOrbit With respect I think it is you who was confused. The question explicitly names the scope exit he is asking about.